# ¿Por que cuando despliego mi aplicacion en glassfish en el servidor se pone lenta y aparece el siguiente error?

Tags: jsf, glassfish

Despliego mi aplicacion en un localhost y funciona perfectamente pero con ya desplegada directamente en el servidor genera el siguiente error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: Primero revisa si tu servidor de aplicaciones se está ejecutando con la cantidad de memoria necesaria. De ser así, te recomiendo sacar un dump de memoria y analizarlo con una herramienta como [Memory Analizer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) para ver dónde puedes tener un posible leak de memoria.